# Postback after button click in ASP.NET causes URL to change

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have an ASP.NET website that uses URL rewrite rules for provides meaningful URLs. The URL:

```
www.example.com/folder/reports/{name}
```

is rewritten to:

```
www.example.com/index.aspx?Title={name}
```

Now, there is a `linkbutton` on the `index.aspx` page (doesn't have any code in the click event). When I click on the button, staying on the URL: `www.example.com/folder/reports/{name}`, instead of staying at the same URL after the post-back, it goes to the URL:
`www.example.com/folder/reports/{name}?Title={name}` and thus shows an error message.

Can someone please explain why the button-click is causing this wrong URL, even though a refresh on the page keeps me at the same page?

Here is my `web.config` rules configuration:

```
<rule name="Rewrite to page">
  <match url="(.*)/reports/(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*(\.html|\.htm|\.aspx)$)" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.aspx?Title={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Could you show use the relevant part if your code and rewrite configuration?

Comment: The rewrite rule in the configuration file is this:               <rule name="Rewrite to page">
   <match url="(.*)/reports/(.*)" />
   <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*(\.html|\.htm|\.aspx)$)" negate="true" />
   </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.aspx?Title={R:2}" />
 </rule>

Comment: And how is this linkbutton generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to clear this problem, by adding this line in the Page_Load event of the master-page:(where 'Form1' is the asp form used in the master-page)

```
Form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;
```